# How to customize popups on "The7" Theme on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, deployment, wordpress-theming, customization, custom-wordpress-pages

As you can see in the image, the "X" to close the pop-up is a little to the right of the visible white box. This has been confusing for some of the less computer savvy users of my site, but I can't figure out where on Wordpress I can go to move it. Can anyone help? I am using The7 theme, associated WPBakery Page Builder and popup maker.

[example of popup asking for personal information with the "x" outside of the viewable box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVRCo.png)

I found a way to edit the theme that is selected for this popup and changed the left and right CSS properties of the button, which seemed to fix it inside the theme edit section, but after saving and returning to the popup, nothing had changed.